# Multiple values in bracket power bi

Tags: expression, dax, powerbi-desktop, qliksense

I have this expression

```
  vOther_OS = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( OS_excel[OS_AMOUNT] ),
Claims_excel[COVER_NAME]={"abc", "def"},Premium_Excel[LOB]="Caar"      
)
```

when i try above expression this shows an error

**"A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"**

so this message clearly shows there should 1 value in bracket where i want more than 1 value

as i do this in qliksense expression

```
sum({<COVER_NAME -= {"abc", "def"},LOB = {'Caar'}>}OS_AMOUNT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
vOther_OS =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( OS_excel[OS_AMOUNT] ),
    Claims_excel[COVER_NAME] IN { "abc", "def" },
    Premium_Excel[LOB] = "Caar"
)
```